# How to open file always in a new window by VSCode?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

(Using `MacOS Mojave, VSCode 1.28.2`)

I'm using VSCode in text editing(like .js, .txt, .csv,...).

When I double click and open a file in Finder or Desktop(or "Open in VSCode"), and if I'm opening another workspace, it opens the file in the same window as the workspace I'm already opening.

How to make VSCode to always open files in a new window?

[image: example]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Set `"window.openFilesInNewWindow": "on"` in `settings.json`.

Click on the gear icon on the bottom-left corner of the window, select `Settings` then enter `window.openFilesInNewWindow` in the search box that appears on the top of the Settings tab to find the setting quickly. Click on it and select "on" from the dropdown list.

It explains (below or above the setting, depending if you use the new Settings manager or edit the `settings.json` file):

> Files will open in a new window.

Comment: I was seeking: "window.openFoldersInNewWindow": "on" behviour.

Answer (score 2):

You can try opening the following:

```
Open the Command pallet using Ctrl+Shift+p
Open user settings(which is a JSON)
Add a new property
"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false
```

and save it

Comment: That's an entirely different setting from what was asked. `enablePreview` is for *not* opening a file in the workspace as a *preview* &mdash; which could potentially overwrite the current editor window.