# How to prevent VS Code remembering files outside work folder?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My workflow with VS Code is to always use project folders on projects. This works great, but there's one thing that's messing things up right now;

When opening just a single file from another project while working in another project, lets's say webpack.config.js, I use Windows Explorer rightclick to open that file in VS Code. However, this always opens the file in the currently open VS Code instance.

This adds the file from that other folder now to the memory of the previously opened files in the open project while it has nothing to do with that project.

When using the quick file open of VS Code now it happens a lot VS Code opens a file from that other folder, only because that outside file has been opened once while I was working on this project.

This is error prone as now it happens a lot, especially when working fast, that the wrong, for instance, package.json or webpack.config.js file gets opened, because VS Code now also suggests files that are outside this project. That's pretty frustrating and causes changes to be made in the wrong files pretty quickly.

I know we can clear the editor history and have to do it a lot now. But to me that's the other way around, doesn't solve the real problem and when not done often the issue remains.

So I want to get rid of this issue and have the following questions:

**1) How can we change the 'Open with Code' rightclick menuitem in Explorer to open files always in a new instance of VS Code?
2) Is there a config settings to disable the behaviour that VS Code remembers files that are outside of the current work folder?**

Thanks in advance, this thing is bothering me for quite some time now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**How can we change the 'Open with Code' rightclick menuitem in Explorer to open files always in a new instance of VS Code?**

I assume you are a Windows user. You can edit the context menu behavior from Regedit.

Follow the below steps:

- Press `Windows` + `R`
- Type `regedit` and press OK
- Go to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\VSCode\command` in regedit
- Add `-n` parameter to the command like below

[image: regedit]

It will help you to open every file in a new window when you use `Open with Code`.

For your second question, **Is there a config settings to disable the behavior that VS Code remembers files that are outside of the current work folder?**

- Open VS Code settings
- Search `window.openFilesInNewWindow`
- Make it off to on like below

[image: vscode]

With this configuration, you can't open new files in the current workspace therefore technically you prevent VS Code remember outside files. Not directly but it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick and very helpful elegant solution to this! Just changed it in the registry and it works like charm! It would be extra nice if somebody also knows the answer to the other question, but this is already a great solution to solve the biggest part of the issue!

Comment: @Friksel I made some research and  I answered the second question too!

Comment: Wow, great find! I've searched through the settings, but couldn't find nor relate this one to solve it. When seeing this answer I was afraid it would open all files in a new window, but that isn't the case. VS Code appears to be smart enough to only open files in a new window when outside the current project folder! So that's exactly what I need! Thanks again, this is really solving a big frustration!

Comment: BTW, Even a nodejs script I run to start VS Code with files from different folders still works; it opens VS Code with an empty tab and after that it opens another VS Code window with all files in it! Exactly what I need! So that still works too and even better, because also that script isn't disturbing an open session anymore! Cool! Thanks for all the effort, this made my day!

Comment: Just in case other people with the same issue find this thread; when setting window.openFilesInNewWindow to 'on'  the regEx change is not even needed anymore!

Comment: Was excited to try this, finding your answer, but under Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell
I don't have "VSCode".  Must be another place I'll have to find later.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like how "recently opened" files are shown in VS Code [Quick Open (<kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd>)](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_quick-file-navigation). I think OP is describing this behavior...

The behavior to remember "recently opened" files causes me problems when I **mistakenly**  open a *temporary/copy* of my file, i.e.

- `C:/users/temp/code.js`

... instead of the *true file* (i.e. located inside the currently-open VS Code project)

- `C:/git/source-control/code.js`

...my confusion happens because because *both files* are listed among the options when I use "Quick Open <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd>" and type "code"

For me , the "Quick Open" list UI can be used to fix this, any "recently-open" files should have an "X" icon on the right side. You may need to hover your mouse over the file you want to remove.

Click the "X" icon to **"Remove from recently open"**. "Quick Open" will always be able to find files in your current project, *even if you remove them from recently-open*:

[image: VS Code "Quick Open" lists some files (names are redacted). The first files in the list are recently open files. Each recently-open-files have an "X" icon on the right, to "Remove from recently open"]

Please note I don't have access to `regedit` as suggested in the accepted answer; my answer here does not require `regedit`.

**UPDATE**

I think the accepted answer approach describes `regedit` **and and a settings change approach**. [OP's comment suggests the **`regedit` change is not required**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69491297/how-to-prevent-vs-code-remembering-files-outside-work-folder/72970468#comment122851451_69491722)

Just change the VS Code settings for [`window.openFilesInNewWindow`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_window-management); change its value to **"on"** as seen in accepted answer, and other answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53186584/1175496) and [here](https://superuser.com/a/1485111/292784)

(My answer might still be helpful for folks who **do** want to open two versions of a file in the **same VS Code window** (i.e. to do side-by-side compares), but afterwards they want to "remove the file from memory")

Comment: This is a different issue. I do think I recognise this tho, but slightly different; there are times that a local file also appears with its full path (to the exact same file) in lists in VS Code. That's also unwanted, but a complete different case.

Comment: I agree @Friksel, the accepted answer is a more permanent fix to the problem (one-time fix to prevent adding to existing VS Code's window memory, vs my fix to "correct" adding to VS Code memory). Nonetheless I think my answer may help some folks. By the way, your comment on accepted answer said "Just in case other people with the same issue find this thread; when setting window.openFilesInNewWindow to 'on' the **regEx** change is not even needed anymore! –" - did you meant the **RegEdit** change is not needed anymore? That's cool, even simpler! Thanks!